# How to structure a Winform app where the 'main form' is not center of all?

Tags: c#, winforms, structure, desktop-application

The conventional way to structure a C# Winform app is to have a main form and create/start it in Program.cs. I have inherited an app that has a 'main' form (lets call it MyMainForm or MMF for short) that gets run from Program.cs in the convention manner `Application.Run(new MMF());`. The MMF ctor does a ton of setup, then opens a fairly complicated startup dialog to get info from the user such as which server(s) to connect with, etc. When the dialog completes, control returns to the MMF ctor which does yet more setup and finally returns. At this point (in my understanding, though I am still new to Winform) I believe the MMF's form is (finally) displayed.

This seems very untidy to my sensibilities. I would rather have a 'main app' class that (1) does all the setup and configuration, then displays the startup dialog, then uses the answers provided on the dialog, does the final internal setup and configuration based on the answers, and finally makes the main form visible.

Is this a viable approach? I especially dislike the fact that the MMF ctor is overburdened with the many setup steps. It seems cleaner to have a main class (instance thereof) that creates / assembles / interconnects the high-level objects of the application, and it would show forms as it needs to in order to interact with the user.

Anyone have an approach (dare I say philosophy) of how to structure a Winform app without having a 'main' form? Doing all the setup work in the ctor of MMF just seems unclean.

Answer (score 0):

Your app needs a main form and I don't think you can even change it, so it is the same main form from beginning to end.

Having said that, you don't have to do all that complicated stuff in the ctor of the main form. Avoid doing anything that is not absolutely crucial for the initialization of the form in the ctor.

You should have other class(es) that encapsulate the business logic (as well as any presentation logic) of your app and in your main form you just construct them and call methods on them for user events (i.e. press of a button). with architecture like that you can have all your business (and presentation) logic testable separate from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, it works sort of like this:

First, you have a splash screen. The splash screen comes up and displays information like your product information and version and such. While the splash screen is display, all your initialization stuff is done. It should be in a class, like this:

```
public class Initialization
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        // Do your initialization stuff here
    }
 }
```

In your main program, you'd have this:

```
 SplashScreen.show();
 Initialization.Initialize();
 SplashScreen.hide();
 ShowStartupDialog.ShowDialog();
 MainForm.show();
```

This will display your splash screen. While its show, your application will do its initialization stuff. It'll then hide the splash screen, then show your startup dialog. Once the user is finished with that dialog, the main form will finally show.

Comment: So where does the Application.Run() call go?  It was my understanding that was what pumped messages and whatnot so that the forms actually work.

Comment: Keep the Application.Run() call how it is. In your MMF class, in the Load event, that's where you'll show the splash screen and do your initialization and what not.